# How to Use Reserved Keywords in a REST Resource?

Tags: apex, api, integration, rest, apexrest

I have configured Plivo SMS in my org. Sending and logging outbound messages is no problem. I have configured a Plivo app to direct inbound SMS to my rest resource to create an inbound record (custom object I've called Plivo_SMS__c), but am having an issue with receiving the "from" number. When I try to define a string labeled "from", I get an error. Here is my basic rest resource:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/sms/*')

Global with sharing class smslog{
@HttpPost
    global static ID createSMSrecord(String MessageUUID, string From,
        string to, String mtype, string Text) {
        Plivo_SMS__C thisPlivo = new Plivo_SMS__C(
            name=messageUUID,
            Fromnum__c=From,
            to__c=to,
            type__c=type,
            SMSmessage__c = text);
         insert thisPlivo;
         return thisPlivo.Id;
    }   

}
```

when I change the string "from" to something like fromnumber, my testing is successful, but the actual POST I receive looks like this:

```
 {'To': '19165555554', 'From': '19165555555', 'Text': 'Example Message', 'Type': 'sms', 'MessageUUID': '015447-b20c-15r6-a746-06anob21425'}
```

I also anticipate a similar issue with the string "type" as well. Is there a way to assign a string variable to a key word? I am uncertain as to the correct way to receive and process this post. Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is more than one way to <s>skin a cat</s> get request parameters. The following approach should work just fine for you if you are trying to use reserved words as parameters. Note that `type` is *not* a [reserved keyword](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_reserved_words.htm) in `Apex`.

```
@RestResource(UrlMapping='/demo')
global with sharing class Throwaway
{
    @HttpPost
    global static void doStuffWithReservedKeywords()
    {
        String fromValue = RestContext.request.params.get('From');
        String type = RestContext.request.params.get('Type');
    }
}
```

Comment: But I wouldn't use the word Type for a variable name, either, just in case someone later decides they want to use the Type "class"...

Comment: You can just use `System.Type` if there is a conflict, and since the scoping is very locally constrained in this case, I would have no qualms with using it myself.